# igraph use of %>% as continuation

Tags: r, igraph

I am using igraph with R
trying to create a graph with  labeled vertices.

THe igraph docs for "paths" give the example code

```
g <- make_empty_graph(directed = FALSE, n = 10) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("name", value = letters[1:10])

plot(g) # labels the vertices with letters a through j
```

However

```
g <- make_empty_graph(directed = FALSE, n = 10)
set_vertex_attr(g, "name", value = letters[1:10])

plot(g) # now labels the vertices as numbers 1:10
```

Why? 
The igraph docs for "set_vertex_attributs"  use

```
set_vertex_attr(g, "name", value = letters[1:10])
```

to set vertex attributes.

Comment: Because R is a functional programming language, functions like `set_vertex_attr()` doesn't change the original graph object `g` but returns a new `g`, so you need to assign the new graph object to `g` if you want to see the changes. `g <- set_vertex_attr(g, "name", value = letters[1:10]); plot(g)`

Comment: Thanks to Psidom. This also  explains the %>% operator nicely -